# Capture the number of 'yes' clicks in a substitute command with confirmation?

Tags: vim, substitution, confirmation

Is it possible to capture the number of 'yes' clicks in a substitute command with confirmation?

p.e.

```
:%s/foo/bar/gc
replace with bar (y/n/a/q/l/^E/^Y)?
```

number of `y` clicks = ?

Comment: you want to know the number or your script wants to know the number?

Comment: What do you want to do with that information?

Comment: @Kent, I want to know the number in a script.

Comment: @romainl, I want to know how many replaces are made (the substitute command is in a function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to know how many substitutions were done (the number of `y`), after all occurrences confirmation were asked, you will see `X substitutusions on Y lines`, the `X` is what you want.

If you are writing a script and you want to get the number in your script. You can either implement this counter in your function, or before the `:s/../../gc`, `redir @x` after all substitutions were done, `redir END`. Read `@x`, take the last line, extract `^\d\+`, that would be the number.

Comment: thank you Kent. You wrote "You can either implement this counter in your function"  You mean to capture `X substitutusions on Y lines`?

Comment: no, I meant, you can implement the `y/n` substitution by yourself, or let vim do it for you (`:s///gc`) and extract the `X` from `X substitutusions on Y lines` line (through `:redir`) @Reman